# 'No' string rendered as numero sign (No.) in react-native-svg Text element with a specific font (RyoGothicPlusN) on ios

Tags: ios, react-native, font-family, react-native-svg

The string 'No' renders as the numero sign № with the font RyoGothicPlusN-Regular on ios only. If I don't pass the font or pass something else f.e. Times New Roman, the string renders as expected.

```
import { Text } from 'react-native-svg';

<Text x="0" y="10" dx="10" fontSize={14} fontFamily="RyoGothicPlusN-Regular">No</Text>
```

Updating the package to the latest did not resolve.
Any ideas that could unblock me?